# Why concatenation of two const char* is not allowed in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I tried the following, which does not work. Why?

```
std::string s = "hello" + "world";
```

Why did the C++ standard library developers decide not to overload `operator+` to implement `char*` concatenation? Would it not make people's lives simpler?

Comment: _Why c++ standard library developers decide not to reload"+" to implement a char* concatenation? It would make people's lives simpler, no?_ Actually, no .. it wouldn't .. As other answers have pointed out, you can remove the `+` and have string literals concatenated, but having the C++ language override the `+` operator _only_ for `const char*` types would actually complicate things. `const char* concatenate(const char* str1, const char* str2) { return str1 + str2; }` .. in this function, if the `+` was overloaded, would their be memory allocated to concatenate?

Comment: Making ppl's lives simpler is NOT the purpose of c/c++. `C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot; C++ makes it harder, but when you do it blows your whole leg off.` Guessing who said that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With two literal strings, you *can* concatenate them, but you don't need any operator, just (optional) spaces. So

```
 std::string s="hello" "world";
```

is allowed and the same as

```
 std::string s="helloworld";
```

Actually, at parsing time, two literal strings are glued together as one. And this also applies to C and happens after preprocessing expansion.

This is [phase 6](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) of the compilation process. Adjacent [string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) are concatenated.

BTW, this only works with string literals. E.g.

```
std::string s1= ((1<2)?"hello":"goodbye") "world"; // wrong
std::string s2= ("ab")"cd"; // wrong
```

are both wrong.

You might also use the [`operator ""s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s)

```
using std::literals::string_literals;
std::string s= "abcd"s + "ef"s;
```

but then both `"abcd"s` and `"ef"s`  denote some constant `std::string`-s and the `+` applies to these.

> Why c++ standard library developers decide not to reload"+" to implement a char* concatenation?

Then you would want to code

```
 char* foo = (rand()%4)?"lucky":"unlucky";
 char* bar = foo + "xy";  // wrong
```

and if such a `+` was implemented, it would need to allocate heap memory (at runtime) à la `strdup` and you would need to decide who and when would that be `delete[]` or `free`-d. BTW, as [r0ng answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45025818/841108) you cannot define an `operator +` on pointer types. So the standard committee decision to not allow that is sane.

However if you replace `char*` above twice with `std::string` it works.

Answer (score 4):

"hello" and "world" are two `const char` pointers. There is no function available to concatenate two `const char` pointers.

You can try the following:

```
std::string("hello") + "world";
std::string("hello") + std::string("world");
```

Comment: But how this answers "_Why did the C++ standard library developers decide not to overload_"?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let‘s see why the `std::string("hello") + "world"` works.
In the std::string class, it has a member function which overloads the '+' operator [see the string operators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+/)

```
string operator + (const string& lhs, const char* rhs);
```

`std::string("hello") + "world"`
is equalent to something like calling the member function from std::string:
`operator + (std::string("hello"), "world")`

char is a primitive type in c/c++, which means not member-function within the type char. So char itself has no member function to overload the + operator.

And if you are going to overload an operation, you have to follow the following rule:
"*When an operator appears in an expression, and at least one of its operands has a class type or an enumeration type*" [reference is here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators). The char is neither a 'class' nor 'enumeration type'.

Hence people are NOT able to create operator like:
`const char* operator +(const char* lhs, const char* rhs)`

That is the reason you can not have "hello"+"world" working.